# Bash shortcut to get parent of last used parameter

Tags: bash

In my workflow I do very usually:

```
cat this/very/long/filename.txt
cd !$
bash: cd: this/very/long/filename.txt: Not a directory
```

Which is to be expected :(

And now I recover the last command, remove manually the file part, and repeat the `cd`, which now works. That is *too much typing*!

It would be sooo nice if there was a `bash` shortcut like:

```
cd !§
```

Which could give me the parent of the last used parameter. I know `!§` does not exist, I just wished it did! Is there something which can satisfy this?

Comment: Might I suggest that this question would be great for SuperUser.SE?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

*Et voilà.*  History modifiers come to the rescue!

```
$ cd !!:$:h
```

which can be abbreviated to

```
$ cd !$:h
```

This command takes the last argument *of the previous command*, and *removes the trailing path name*.

In more details:

1. `!!` expands to the previous command
2. `:$` expands to the last argument of the previous command
3. `:h` takes the *header*; that is, removes the file name (which is the trailing part of the above last argument)

As an aside,

```
!!:$:t
```

does exactly the opposite.

For an in-depth discussion, please refer to [the Bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html).

Comment: Thanks! This is not very easy to type (and remember), but is better than the workflow I was using.

Comment: `!!$` and `!$` *seem* to be equivalent to `!!:$`. What is the difference? Why would you use `!!:$` when two shorter alternatives exist?

Comment: @RobW `!!:$` and `!$` *are equivalent*, indeed (cf. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Designators.html#Word-Designators).  I got my answer updated.  Thank you!

Comment: @RobertoReale What does the colon(`:`) in `:h` and `:$` mean?

Comment: @Geek The colon is just a separator.  Please take a look at the relevant chapter in the documentation (I provided a link in my answer).

Answer (score 16):

This shorter version would also work:

```
cd !$:h
```

Details:

- `!$` is synonymous to `!!:$` which presents the last argument of the previous command.
- `:` separates the modifier from the event-word designator.
- `h` is the modifier that removes the trailing file name component.

Answer (score 7):

Building on the answer presented by several other people,
the ideal workflow is to type `cd !$:h` after the `cat this/very/long/filename.txt` command. 
This answer, `cd !$:h`, will still work after `cd !$`, but,  once you’ve made that mistake,
you can use the even shorter `!:h`, which repeats the last command (`cd this/very/long/filename.txt`),
but taking only the head of the last word.

I'm using these little-known shorthands:

- `!word_designator` is equivalent to `!!:word_designator`
  for non-numeric *word_designator*s (e.g., `!$` is equivalent to `!!:$`) and
- `!:modifier` is equivalent to `!!:modifier`
  (e.g., `!:h` is equivalent to `!!:h`).

Comment: @konsolebox: (1) “I answered `cd !$:h` already.” Yes, I know. When I said, “Building on the answer presented by several other people, the ideal workflow is to type `cd !$:h` …”, I was acknowledging the previous answers and identifying yours as having a very good piece. Would you have preferred that I acknowledge you by name in my answer? (2) I did upvote your answer.

Comment: @konsolebox: (3) “Seriiusly [sic] why do people keep answering answers that were already answered by others.” Because there’s more than one possible answer. For example, I believe that I was the first to say that `!:h` can be used after `cd !$` (which fails). (4) Also, I believe that I was the first to explain that `!!:(something)` can often be abbreviated to `!(something)` or `!:(something)` – which *you* have subsequently copied, but with less generality.

Comment: *"Seriiusly (obvious typo) why do people keep answering answers that were already answered by others."* ... *Because there’s more than one possible answer.* -> I'm only referring to my specific answer `cd !$:h`. And I hope you don't mean I copied from yours or from somebody else.

Answer (score 6):

In this case, I usually do: (I have emacs key binding)

`cd` <kbd>Alt-dot</kbd><kbd>Alt-b</kbd>(n times)<kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd>

better:

`cd`<kbd>Alt-dot</kbd><kbd>ALT-Backspace</kbd>(n times)

note <kbd>alt-b</kbd> or <kbd>ALT-Bs</kbd> could be pressed multiple times, till you are satisfied with the path.

Comment: I find <kbd>Alt-Backspace</kbd> more useful for this since it is backward-kill-word. Something bound to `unix-filename-rubout` would be even better but that isn't bound by default.

Comment: @EtanReisner thank you for pointing it out. I usually use zsh, there I have `ctrl-w` to delete **word**, but in bash, `ctrl-w` is for deleting **WORD**, not **word**, and I didn't find the right one, so I `alt-b` times.  Tried your comment, `alt-BS` is the key.

Answer (score 5):

```
cat this/very/long/filename.txt
cd !!^:h
cd this/very/long
```

- `!!` refers to the last command
- `^` first argument, second word(word designators)
- `:h` remove trailing pathname component, leaving the head(modifers).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of navigating through the history, you can also consider the use of the `$_` variable to refer to the last argument of the previous command (see `_` under the *Special Parameters* section of `bash(1)`).

To further strip the filename component ("everything after, and including, the last slash"), use parameter expansion (Remove matching suffix pattern):

```
$ cat this/very/long/filename.txt
$ cd ${_%/*}
```

The last command will be `cd this/very/long` since `/filename.txt` got stripped. A difference with history expansion is that this command (`cd ${_%/*}`) gets added to the history.